# Can I create dynamically resizable Views?

Tags: android, gestures

I am currently attempting to create an mp3 player that relies on gestural interaction. In particular I wish to use direct manipulation in my system. One particular feature I wish to have is a circle on the screen representing the volume level; the bigger the circle the louder the volume and so on. The user would use a pinch zoom gesture to change the size of the circle.

How would I go about implementing this? Is it possible to define a view that can be dynamically resized?

Comment: Do you mean a control, or a widget? Controls can be essentially anything.

Comment: I apologize, I suppose I mean control

Comment: If I've read you correctly, you are using 'widget' to mean what are called 'views' in android (but widgets in X): elements you make you screen out of. You can create and manipulate views to do whatever you want by picking a View which is close to what you want and customising it by extending that class. Or you can extend the View class and override the onDraw call, allowing you to make the View show whatever you want. See http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html and other "android custom view tutorial" search results.